# Check In and Check Out using APIS

Tags: social-tables

I have tried to check In and check Out a Bulk guest using **/4.0/guestlists/{guestlist_id}/guests/_bulk** API function. But it's not updating the status. Except for Status, it is updating everything. Can anyone help me out to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Social Tables API doesn't currently support updating the *checked_in_status* using the **/4.0/guestlists/{guestlist_id}/guests/_bulk** route.

To achieve this functionality you will need to use:

**/4.0/guestlists/{guestlist_id}/guests/checkin**

body:

```
{
    guests: ["guest_id_1", "guest_id_2"],
    event_name: "Some Event Name"       // optional. used by check-in notifictations
}
```

This currently does not support setting to checked-out or to reset the Guest to non checked-in state. If this is the desired functionality please let us know and we can add it to our external API.

Please feel free to ask if you have any other questions!

**UPDATED**

You can now provide a checked-in status to the bulk check-in route

```
{
  "guests": [
    "99b4ae20-2779-11e6-b0b7-13c2616041ae",
    "99b4ae21-2779-11e6-b0b7-13c2616041ae"
  ],
  "checked_in": 1,
  "event_name": "Some Event Name"       // optional. used by check-in notifictations
}
```

Comment: Hi Ben,

Thanks for your help, Yes we required all three functionalities checked in not checked in and checkout in bulk.It will great if you can provide external API functions ASAP as we stuck.

Comment: Hi Ben, Any update on it.Can you please tell me when you can provide external API functions?

Comment: @VishalAgrawal here is the new route that should do what you are looking for: [Check-in Bulk](https://developer-portal.socialtables.com/api-console#!/CHECKIN/post_4_0_guestlists_guestlist_id_guests_checkin)